# Are all resonance forms of pyracyclene equivalent?

Tags: aromatic-compounds, resonance

This is pyracyclene:

[image]

If I’m correct, pyracyclene has four resonance forms (double carbon bonds shown in red):

[image]

Now my problem is estimating the dominance of each form. Are they equal or is there one which is more dominant?

This is what I’ve got so far:

Rules for estimating stability of resonance structures

- The greater the number of covalent bonds, the greater the stability since more atoms will have complete octets.
- The structure with the least number of formal charges is more stable.
- The structure with the least separation of formal charge is more stable.
- A structure with a negative charge on the more electronegative atom will be more stable.
- Positive charges on the least electronegative atom (most electropositive) is more stable.
- Resonance forms that are equivalent have no difference in stability and contribute equally (eg. Benzene).

Pyracyclene has the same carbon atoms, the same number of covalent bonds and a formal charge of zero. I don’t see any difference in stability either. So it seems that all forms are equivalent.

Is this correct?

Comment: Good question! You've picked a molecule for which the answer is not entirely clear, from what I've just gleaned from recent and earlier publications. Welcome to chem.SE!

Comment: Which means that treating it as a generic homework, like OP did, isn't a good idea.

Comment: BTW when structures are equivalent, then there no difference at all. It doesn't have anything to do with some lame rule of thumb.

Comment: The top right and bottom left are the same by 180 rotation, the other two are related in the same way as the double bonds are in naphthalene (or benzene) by a shift single to double bond.  Whether these two types are the same is hard to assess. Have you looked for any experimental evidence, gas phase spectroscopy, or  xray of single crystals for example?

Comment: These rules are at least very sloppy worded. There cannot be a most stable resonance structure as these are all just hypothetical configurations; they simply do not exist on their own. So what you want to know or what these rules refer to are the relative contribution to the overall bonding description. Because of overall symmetry, I'd expect different contributions. A calculation might actually offer some insight into the structure as well as the bonding structure. But I unfortunately don't have the tools for that anymore.

Comment: What kind of calculation should be done? Do we expect large or small differences in contributions?